# Do 3 consecutive primes always form a triangle?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are any three consecutive primes other than the triple $2$, $3$, and $5$.  Do they satisfy the triangle inequalities: $a + b > c$;  $b + c > a$;  $c + a > b$?  In other words, can we always form a triangle with sides being the $3$ successive prime numbers?  Is this a well-known result?  Where can I read about its proof or refutation?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried any small examples, say starting at $2$?

Comment: Let me clarify my question.  I know that the first 3 successive primes, 2, 3, and 5 do not satisfy the triangular inequalities.  If we discard them, does the above condition hold true for the rest of the consecutive primes?

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** Use a stronger form of Bertrand's postulate, which states that $p_ {n+1} < 1.1 \times  p_{n}$ for large enough $n$.

As such, $p_{n-1} + p_{n} > p_{n+1}$ satisfies the triangle inequality.

This means that we only need to check finitely many small cases, which is easy to do.

Comment: It suffices to use $p_{n+1} < 1.6 p_n$, which is true for $n\ge 3$ and covers all cases.

Comment: @anorton I fixed the obvious typo, this is what he meant

Comment: @Calvin.  Thanks, but I don't understand your hint.  Could you please elaborate?  Are you saying that the conjecture is true?  Is this a well-known result?

Comment: @user67724 It follows immediately from the Prime Number Theorem, but it is probably easy to prove directly by the Erdos method too. I don't know if it easy to estimate what "for large $n$" means, which is important because one need to manually check those.

Answer (score 7):

Let $p_n,p_{n+1}, p_{n+2}$ be three consecutive primes.

You need to show that

$$p_{n+2}< p_{n}+p_{n+1}$$

This follows immediately from the following stronger version of the Betrand Postulate: For $n \geq 7$ there are two primes between $n$ and $2n$.

The case $2,3,5$ is obviously a counterexample, an easy check up to 7 shows there is no other.

P.S. Does anyone have a good reference to this stronger version of the BP?
It follows from last statement of this [Paper](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/karcher/BertrandN_2N.pdf), but I remember seeing once that statement written explicitely..

Answer (score 0):

I just love answering old questions :) ... basically:

1. Bertrand's Postulate $p_{n+1} < 2 \cdot p_n$
2. From ([Limit inferior of the quotient of two consecutive primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144539/limit-inferior-of-the-quotient-of-two-consecutive-primes/420475)) $$\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{p_{n+1}}{p_{n}}=1 \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{p_{n+1}}{p_{n-1}}=\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{p_{n+1}}{p_{n}} \cdot \frac{p_{n}}{p_{n-1}}=1$$  or $$p_{n+1} < 2 \cdot p_{n-1}$$ from some $n$.

As a result:

$$p_{n-1}+p_{n}\geq 2 \cdot \sqrt{p_{n-1} \cdot p_{n}}= \sqrt{2 \cdot p_{n-1} \cdot 2 \cdot p_{n}} > p_{n+1}$$