# Can a prime number be bigger than the sum of adding the previous twin primes (other than 13)?

Tags: prime-numbers, soft-question, twin-primes

A simple heuristic of the first million primes shows that no prime number can be bigger than the sum of adding the previous twin primes.

Massive update:
@mathlove made a comment that leaves me completely embarrassed. $13 > 7 + 5$ I don’t know how I missed it and I deeply apologize to everyone!

I ask anyone qualified to suggest any edits for the question.

$7 < 5 + 3$

$11 < 7 + 5$

$17 < 11 + 13$

$23 < 17 + 19$

At larger numbers:

$4886639 < 4886489 + 4886491$

$5389451 < 5388869 + 5388871$

$3155597 < 3154757 + 3154759$

I assume that if it could be proved, it would prove the twin prime conjecture of whether twin primes exist forever.

So I am not exactly seeking for a proof, but rather for possible explanations or references for why it is assumed true (or not)?

Also as the list grows, there seems to be a range for how small or big can a prime be in comparison to the sum of adding the previous twin primes.

As the list grows, a prime is usually never bigger or smaller than slightly above $50\%$ of the sum of the previous twin primes. Any references for such a range will be appreciated too.

*Update: When mentioning "the previous twin primes", I am implying to:  $(107, 109), 113, 127, 131, (137, 139)$.

$131 < 107 +109$

Comment: Could it have something to do with Bertrand's postulate?

Comment: Bertrand's Postulate says that the next prime number is less than 2× the last. But that is a very loose bound I think, as for "most" integers $n$ the next prime is no larger than $n +\log n < 2n$ or so. So the next prime should be only a factor of $1+\epsilon$ than the last by the time you are up to 4, 5, 6 digits

Comment: The last twin prime may be much smaller than the last prime, which separates it from Bertrand's Postulate in some ways.

Comment: It was proved already, for any $3$ consecutive prime numbers, check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413163/do-3-consecutive-primes-always-form-a-triangle/).

Comment: @rtynase It seems as if the proof is in regards to the sum addition of the previous primes and not previous twin primes

Comment: @IsaacBrenig, does it matter? If it is true for any 3 consecutive prime numbers, it is true for consecutive triplets containing "previous twin primes" as well. Also, this answers the heuristic part of your question, from the beginning.

Comment: @IsaacBrenig, I am rarely confusing anything. You asked for hints ;)

Comment: @rtybase I am sorry, I am the one that is confused, You aren't confusing, but  I thought that maybe you are confused by my description. Your hints are greatly appreciated and probably correct, but i still need a click in my brain ;)

Comment: $13$ is bigger than $5+7$.

Comment: @mathlove you are more than welcomed to answer or edit the question. I have already updated the question to give you credit.

Comment: Is it known that there is a pair of twin primes between $n$ and $4n$? If there are no twin primes between $n$ and $4n$, and if $p$ is a prime between $2n$ and $4n$ (which exists by Bertrand's postulate), then $p$ is bigger than the sum of the preceding pair of twin primes, which are less than $n$.

Comment: @bof It is not even known whether infinite many twin primes exist , not alone between $n$ and $4n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's modify the OP's observation as follows:

> Let $(p,p+2)$ and $(q,q+2)$ be *consecutive* pairs of twin primes,
> e.g., $(107,109)$ and $(137,139)$. Then (conjecturally) $q\lt2p+2$.

This is, essentially, a Bertrand's Postulate for twin primes, and it's not hard to confirm that it holds for entries at the outset for the sequence [$3,5,11,17,29,41,59,\ldots$](https://oeis.org/A001359).  The basic explanation can be found in the [heuristic twin-prime "theorem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime#First_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture) $\pi_2(x)\sim2C_2x/(\ln x)^2$, although arguing that it (conjecturally) holds for *all* twin primes, not just for ones that are sufficiently large -- i.e., giving a (heuristic) twin-prime analog of the [proof of Bertrand's Postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand%27s_postulate) -- seems problematic.

Remark: Amusingly, the modification proposed above of the OP's observation is technically agnostic with regard to the twin prime conjecture. Indeed, it would be easiest, in principle, to prove (or disprove) if there were an identifiable *last* pair of twin primes.

Answer (score 0):

**Futher to my comments ...**

For any $3$ consecutive primes (**regardless** of if they contain twin primes or not) $p_{n},p_{n+1},p_{n+2}$, [it's true that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413163/do-3-consecutive-primes-always-form-a-triangle)
$$\frac{p_{n+1}+p_{n}}{2}<p_{n+2}<p_{n+1}+p_{n}$$
In fact, $\forall p_{n+k}\geq p_{n+2}$ we have $p_{n+k} > p_{n+1}$ and $p_{n+k} > p_{n}$, thus
$$\frac{p_{n+1}+p_{n}}{2}<p_{n+k}$$
For a **fixed** $k$, we can show that
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_{n+k}}{p_{n}}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_{n+k}}{p_{n+1}}=1 \tag{1}$$
This means that for large enough $n$'s we have
$$p_{n+k}<2p_{n} \text{ and } p_{n+k}<2p_{n+1}$$
Applying [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) yields
$$p_{n+1}+p_{n}\geq 2\sqrt{p_{n+1}\cdot p_{n}}=\sqrt{2p_{n+1}\cdot 2p_{n}}> 
\sqrt{p_{n+k}^2}=p_{n+k}$$
for **large enough** $n$'s, or
$$\frac{p_{n+1}+p_{n}}{2}<p_{n+k}<p_{n+1}+p_{n} \tag{2}$$
The range of the **fixed** $k$ depends on when $(1)$ gets less than $2$.

---

**A few words** about $(1)$, it is true because of [this limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144539/limit-inferior-of-the-quotient-of-two-consecutive-primes/420475)
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_{n}}=1$$
then
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_{n+k}}{p_{n}}=
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_{n+k}}{p_{n+k-1}}\cdot
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_{n+k-1}}{p_{n+k-2}}\cdot ...\cdot
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_{n}}=1$$
again, for a **fixed** $k$!

Comment: but my question is not in regards to 3 consecutive prime numbers

Comment: In the example provided by *Update in the post, you will notice that they are not 3 consecutive prime numbers

Comment: @IsaacBrenig, it's a story line. It starts with 3 consecutive and ends with $p_{n}, p_{n+1}$ (which could be twin) and $p_{n+k}$, check $(2)$.

Comment: now I get it. So the “could be twin” is completely probabilistic. But could there be an explanation, since the heuristic is 100% proof, or is it also just a Flux?

Comment: Well, all the maths above is a pretty solid explanation of the pattern you see, for large enough $n$'s, of course. What's left 1) finding the range of $k$ and 2) finding the initial $N(k)$ for which $(2)$ is true for $\forall n \geq N(k)$. That won't be a trivial exercise though, but we know that such a range and $N(k)$ exist.

Comment: Here come the downvoters ... I should have closed this account years ago :(

Comment: I don’t understand why the downvote, your answer was still helpful.