# prove that $\frac{a_n}{n}\rightarrow 1$: strange contest problem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math

A friend of mine told me about a contest problem, which he had once seen but the provenance of which he could not remember:

An infinite sequence of positive integers $a_i$ has this property: for every prime $p$, the set $\{ a_1,a_2,...,a_p\}$ is a complete residue system modulo $p$. Now prove that $\frac{a_n}{n}$ converges to $1$.

1) Does anyone recognise this problem and know whence it comes?

2) I would like a solution. Though I have not solved it myself, I have made a curious observation. Denoting the primes by $p_i$, the sequence with these blocks $[p_n,p_n-1,...,p_{n-1}+1]$ is admissible. The statement in the problem then implies that $\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}$ tends to $1$. Rarely does a contest problem say anything about the distribution of the primes.

**EDIT: My curiosity about this problem is growing day by day, but my progress is not. I would be thrilled about and grateful for a solution, whatever techniques are employed.**

Comment: It took me a minute to understand your block structure in 2), so it might be worth explaining that a bit better. (Just to make sure: your blocks are essentially [2, 1], [3], [5, 4], [7, 6], [11, 10, 9, 8], [13, 12], [17, 16, 15, 14], etc, correct?)

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding, your collection is just a simple reordering of $a_i=i$.  How does that construction show that the ratio of successive primes goes to $1$?

Comment: @lulu Because the $p_n$th term in his sequence is $p_{n-1}+1$, so it must be that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_{n-1}+1}{p_n}=1$ since it's a subsequence of $a_n$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki  Ah, thank you.  I may have it wrong, but I believe that proving that limit requires the Prime Number Theorem (or at least something close to it).

Comment: Also, I should note that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}=1$ isn't actually that strong a result; it would hold if you had e.g. $p_n\approx n^2$, and IIRC it's pretty straightforward to show a quadratic bound on the $n$th prime. (Though note that that's not quite enough to show the limit in and of itself, because it's possible the limit could not exist at all; it's more just that the limit doesn't say much about the asymptotic growth of the primes that isn't pretty straightforward.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki it is still more powerful than, say, Bertrand's postulate, although asymptotically.

Comment: Just as a side note, using [Rosser's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) it is easy to show $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{p_{n}}{p_{n+1}}=1$, for example [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144539/limit-inferior-of-the-quotient-of-two-consecutive-primes/420475#420475)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is problem 4 from the 2015 [Miklós Schweitzer contest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikl%C3%B3s_Schweitzer_Competition). There is an AoPS thread discussing this problem, see [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1161484p5531587). A couple of solutions is given there.