# Show that $(p_{k}^2+6p_{k}+8)x_{k}-(8p_{k}+24)>0$

Tags: real-analysis, prime-numbers

I found this exercise:

Show that $$(p_{k}^2+6p_{k}+8)x_{k}-(8p_{k}+24)>0$$ for sufficiently large $k$ where $p_{k}$ is the $k^{th}$ prime and $0<x_{k}=O\left(\frac{1}{k+1}\right)$ where $O$ is the big $O$ notation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99502/discussion-on-question-by-germany-show-that-p-k26p-k8x-k-8p-k24).

Answer (score 2):

Whatever $p_k$ is (you did not specify it), the claim is false as long as $p_k$ is positive for each $k$. To see this, set $x_k = \min\{\frac{8p_k+24}{p_k^2+6p_k+8},\frac 1k\}$. Then $x_k$ decays as desired and the expression is always non-positive.

Answer (score 1):

From $$(p_{k}^2+6p_{k}+8)x_{k}-(8p_{k}+24)>0 \iff\\
\left((p_{k}+3)^2-1\right)x_{k}-8(p_{k}+3)>0 \iff\\
(p_k+3)\left(\left((p_{k}+3)-\frac{1}{p_k+3}\right)x_{k}-8\right)>0 \iff\\$$
sinse $(p_k+3)>0$ anyway ...
$$\left((p_{k}+3)-\frac{1}{p_k+3}\right)x_{k}-8>0 \iff \\
(p_{k}+3)x_{k}>8+\frac{x_{k}}{p_k+3} \iff$$
$$\color{red}{\frac{p_{k}+3}{p_{k+1}}}\cdot\color{blue}{\frac{p_{k+1}}{(k+1)\ln{(k+1)}}}\cdot\ln{(k+1)}\cdot\left(x_{k}(k+1)\right)>8+\frac{x_{k}}{p_k+3} \tag{1}$$
For the red one see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144539/limit-inferior-of-the-quotient-of-two-consecutive-primes/420475), for the blue one [PNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number), obviously $\ln{(k+1)}\to\infty$. [From](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition)
$$0<x_n=O\left(\frac{1}{k+1}\right)<\frac{M}{k+1}$$
the RHS of $(1)$ goes to $8$.

---

**However**, the $x_{k}(k+1)$ part could lead to troubles for some $x_n=O\left(\frac{1}{k+1}\right)$. If you demand that $x_n \sim \frac{1}{k+1}$ (**!!!**) instead, such that $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}x_{k}(k+1)=1$ (or any positive constant), **then** your claim **is right**, since $\ln{(k+1)}$ will outweigh $8$ in $(1)$ from some big $k$ onwards.