# Is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}=1$ where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime number?

Tags: number-theory, limits, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

I've just been wondering: Is
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}=1$$
Essentially I am asking if the primes become more spread out the larger they are, or if the ratio between successive terms decreases adymptotically to $1$. Thanks for any comments or responses.

Comment: Yes it is, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144539/limit-inferior-of-the-quotient-of-two-consecutive-primes/420475#420475).

Comment: @rtybase thanks for that, interesting!